# Why is [branch "development"] not present in .git/config?

Tags: git, branch, git-config

My questions are why does the following `.git/config` file not have a `[branch "development"]` section; what does adding a section like that do; and how can I test out what is really going on, like with a dummy file?

Here are the details:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = test@test:test.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

I have both a master and development branch. As expected, when I `git checkout development` I can make changes in development that are not in master. Later, I can merge development back into master.

I'm confused as to why the development branch is not configured in `.git/config`.

Comment: If development has no remote counterpart, it doesn't need anything in your config.  That is: if development is a local-only branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you have no upstream/remote associated with `development`, thus no config entry is needed. If you push it to origin with `git push origin development -u`, you should then see it in your config.

Comment: You are correct. I don't have complicated enough development to warrant a separate development tree for upstream? Not part of my config, after doing as you suggest, which is what caused me to write the OP.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus - somehow I did not provide the final "u" in my original answer; I have fixed it; try `git push origin development -u`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused as to why the development branch is not configured in `.git/config`.

You simply don't have an upstream or a tracking definition for he given branch.

---

#### Why there is no tracking branch or upstream?

Its actually depends on you git version, since it was updated in git version 2.0.

If you have clones/created the repo in an older version of git (<2.0) this is the reason why you dont have upstream/tracking branches.

You can read all about it in here:
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt

---

> When `git push [$there]` does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional `matching` semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).  **In Git 2.0**, the default is now the `simple` semantics,
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable `push.default` to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   `matching` semantics, you can set the variable to `matching`, for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.

Comment: Older versions of Git absolutely had tracking branches.  You are misunderstanding what changed in 2.0.

Comment: I agree, but before v2.0 it had to be set manually in some cases

Comment: 2.0 only changed the push.default setting.  The change to make `git checkout <branch>` automatically track where branch existed on a single remote happened prior to that.  The problem in the original question can easily happen with 2.7, since there is no requirement that branches track anything.